# How to check for a value in a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My Array is below

```
$sample_arr = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [index] => 0
                [in_id] => 309
                [date] => 2016-08-01
                [article_Id] => 4
                [qty] => 50
                [ref] => ref
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [index] => 1
                [in_id] => 309
                [date] => 2016-08-01
                [article_Id] => 6
                [qty] => 20
                [ref] => ref 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [index] => 2
                [in_id] => 309
                [date] => 2016-08-01
                [article_Id] => 6
                [qty] => 21
                [ref] => ref 2
            )

    )
```

As you can see in the above array there is article_Id twice in the array with value 6

I would like to find the details of the second row so that I can make the second row qty 41 i.e my result array will be like the one below

I have tried the in_array function but still there is something missing

I also tried with the foreach but the problem is that how to get the first appearance row qty? i.e in the $sample_arr when the user adds the third record with article_Id 6 the second row must be updated as shown below

```
 $result_arr = Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [index] => 0
                    [in_id] => 309
                    [date] => 2016-08-01
                    [article_Id] => 4
                    [qty] => 50
                    [ref] => ref
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [index] => 1
                    [in_id] => 309
                    [date] => 2016-08-01
                    [article_Id] => 6
                    [qty] => 41
                    [ref] => ref goes here
                )

        )
```

Comment: Question is not So clear//

Comment: article_Id is unique

Comment: yes article_Id is unique. When we add the same article_Id again the qty of the first record must be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like article ID is unique. So, we can kep storing data in this $newArray variable with the key as article ID.

Every time, it's checked if a record containing the article id exists. If so, the quantity is added. If not, it's appended to the $newArray.

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($sample_arr as $arr) {
    if (isset($newArray[$arr['article_Id']])) {
        $newArray[$arr['article_Id']]['qty'] += $arr['qty'];
        $newArray[$arr['article_Id']]['ref'] = 'Ref goes here';  // If this the string that replaces the ref  
    } else {
        $newArray[$arr['article_Id']] = $arr;
    }
}

$newArray = array_values($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [index] => 0
        [in_id] => 309
        [date] => 2016-08-01
        [article_Id] => 4
        [qty] => 50
        [ref] => ref
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [index] => 1
        [in_id] => 309
        [date] => 2016-08-01
        [article_Id] => 6
        [qty] => 41
        [ref] => ref 2
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$new_merged_array = array();

if(!empty($sample_arr )){
    foreach($sample_arr  as $sample_ar){
        if(!empty($sample_ar) && isset($sample_ar['article_Id'])){
            if(isset($new_merged_array[$sample_ar['article_Id']])){
                $new_merged_array[$sample_ar['article_Id']]['qty'] += $sample_ar['qty'];
            }else{
                $new_merged_array[$sample_ar['article_Id']] = $sample_ar;
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($new_merged_array);
```

Output will be:

```
Array(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [index] => 0
            [in_id] => 309
            [date] => 2016-08-01
            [article_Id] => 4
            [qty] => 50
            [ref] => ref
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [index] => 1
            [in_id] => 309
            [date] => 2016-08-01
            [article_Id] => 6
            [qty] => 41
            [ref] => ref 2
        )
)
```

Another way:

```
$new_merged_array = $sample_array = array();

if(!empty($sample_arr )){
    foreach($sample_arr  as $sample_ar){
        if(!empty($sample_ar) && isset($sample_ar['article_Id'])){
            if(isset($new_merged_array[$sample_ar['article_Id']])){
                $new_merged_array[$sample_ar['article_Id']]['qty'] += $sample_ar['qty'];
            }else{
                $new_merged_array[$sample_ar['article_Id']] = $sample_ar;
            }
        }
    }
}

if(!empty($new_merged_array )){
    foreach($new_merged_array  as $new_merged_arr){
        $sample_array[] = $new_merged_arr;
    }
}
print_r($sample_array);
```

Output will be:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [index] => 0
            [in_id] => 309
            [date] => 2016-08-01
            [article_Id] => 4
            [qty] => 50
            [ref] => ref
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [index] => 1
            [in_id] => 309
            [date] => 2016-08-01
            [article_Id] => 6
            [qty] => 41
            [ref] => ref 2
        )
)
```

Comment: cheers for your effort. But I got the answer from **Object Manipulator** two minutes earlier.

Comment: @Preethy Okay. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$sample_arr = array
    (
    0 => array
    (
        'index'=> 0,
        'in_id' => 309,
        'date' => '2016-08-01',
        'article_Id' => 4,
        'qty' => 50,
        'ref' => 'ref'
    ),
    1 => array
    (
        'index' => 1,
        'in_id' => 309,
        'date' => '2016-08-01',
        'article_Id' => 6,
        'qty' => 20,
        'ref' => 'ref 2'
    ),
    2 => array
    (
        'index' => 2,
        'in_id' => 309,
        'date' => '2016-08-01',
        'article_Id' => 6,
        'qty' => 21,
        'ref' => 'ref 2'
    )
);

$articleArray = [];
foreach($sample_arr as $key=>$value){   
    $articleId = $value['article_Id'];
    if(array_key_exists($articleId,$articleArray)){
        $articleArray[$articleId]['qty'] = $articleArray[$articleId]['qty'] + $value['qty'];
    }else{
        $articleArray[$articleId] = $value;
    }
}
$articleArray = array_values($articleArray);

print_r($sample_arr);
print_r($articleArray);
```

> [Demo](https://3v4l.org/qfITl)

Comment: magizhchi for your effort. But I got the answer from **Object Manipulator** couple of minutes earlier.

Comment: மகிழ்ச்சி :) @Preethy

Answer (score -2):

in_array() does not work on multidimensional arrays. You could write a recursive function to do that for you:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
$b = array(array("Mac", "NT"), array("Irix", "Linux"));
echo in_array_r("Irix", $b) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```